# authentication.getPrincipal() is always String instead of UserDetails

Tags: spring, spring-security

In my `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` I have this:

```
@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(this.userDetailsService);
    return daoAuthenticationProvider;
}
```

and the following in the `UserDetailsService`:

```
@Service
public class AppUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        AppUserEntity appUserEntity = this.appUserRepository.findByUsername(username).orElseThrow(() ->
            new ResourceNotFoundException("Current user not found."));

        return new AppUserDetails(appUserEntity);
    }

}
```

However, I cannot fetch my `AppUserDetails implements UserDetails` object with

```
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
// Throws exception because the principal is a String
AppUserDetails appUserDetails = (AppUserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
```

because `authentication.getPrincipal()` always returns just a `String` (in this case the user's username). However, I expected it to return a `AppUserDetails`. Why is this not the case and how can I change this?

---

I have tried

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getDetails()
```

but this returns `OAuth2AuthenticationDetails` and not the `UserDetails` I was hoping for.

---

Trying [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31723354/826983) won't work either. The returned `details` object is `null`.

```
OAuth2Authentication oAuth2Authentication =
                (OAuth2Authentication) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

Authentication userAuthentication = oAuth2Authentication.getUserAuthentication();

Object details = userAuthentication.getDetails();
```

Comment: @dur My apologies. This version did not make it into my question. The problem here is that the object returned is null. I recall that I have tried that already

Comment: Did you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35056169/how-to-get-custom-user-info-from-oauth2-authorization-server-user-endpoint. There are some attempts. Maybe one works for you.

Comment: Same question here.

Comment: any update on this?